# Anyone using CiviCRM for Scholarship Management?

Tags: joomla, extension, gift-aid-extension

I'm working with a nonprofit's foundation to find a system to manage the foundation and its scholarships. Is anyone using CiviCRM and any extensions for this purpose? Thanks.

Comment: I think the community will be able to help you more if you can spell out some of the scenarios required, since your needs could be very different from another's.

Answer (score 1):

Without information from you this answer is just waving in the dark but here goes.

Assuming a Scholarship involves

- an application
- a review/decision
- a notification of outcome
- for succesful, a one-off or series of payments
- perhaps a report at the end

Then I would approach this by using CiviCase and a bunch of custom Activity Types.

In an iDrupal world I would then provide the user with forms using webform_civicrm to open and update the status of the Case while also creating or updating the relevant Activities.

I would probably also provide a Drupal View of current applicants so admins can easily click through to a prefilled Webform and make the relevant updates.

Webform can also take care of pushing out the success/failure notifications, or that could be triggered via CiviRules or directly via an Activity to let applicants know the outcome.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is very helpful! Yes, your assumptions are 100% correct. (And apologies for not spelling that out initially.) I have never used CiviCRM but in my research it looks like it is flexible enough to provide the tools needed. My question was posed the way it was because of my experience with Joomla which has many extensions that are designed for specific applications. I believe that CivicCRM has a more mature relationship with Drupal as opposed to Joomla so I can certainly look in that direction.